# Email Notification upon insert on PostgresSQL Database Table

Tags: postgresql, email, html-email

I have a Table called ***Teamstores*** in a **PostgreSQL Database**, within that Table I have the Fields **ID (Int), Name (Varchar) and status_id (int)** among others.

What I am looking for is that when some user makes an Insert to the Table with status_id with a value of 10 (The status we occupy for New), the Database itself sends an email to at least one or several Email Addresses as a notification, giving us a Table saying the ID, Name and Status.

Is this possible, I searched online for articles but they are quite complex.

Thank you

Comment: I fully agree with Laurenz.  How are users inserting data?  The application that handles the inserts should send the emails, not the database.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a seriously bad idea unless such inserts happen very rarely.

You could write a trigger function in PL/Python or PL/Perl that sends the e-mail.
With “untrusted” procedural languages you could use any module that makes sending mail comfortable.